# Error Starting Wildfly 11 After JDK 1.8 Update

Tags: java, java-8, wildfly, wildfly-11

We have an existing client production instance using Wildfly 11 and for compliance with the PCIDSS (vulnerabilities), we are required to perform patching on some of the identified vulnerabilities in the machine. We tried upgrading the JDK from version 8u161 to 8u382. However, after we updated that, it throws an initialization error. Consequently, the application instance could not connect to the DB although we can run the the admin console.

Below is the error that it throws:

[image]

We had to revert the JDK back to 8u161 to get it working. However for this JDK upgrade we could not figure out whether there's a known issue in Wildfly 11 or if there's a special setting / patching that needs to be included to resolve this. There have been several conflicting answers - one is adding a 10 minute time limit to the blocking timeout setting, another is upgrading to a later Wildfly (e.g Wildfly 15).

Are there any other alternatives that I can try out asides that?

Comment: Don't post error messages, stacktraces, etc as images; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551.  In this case, the image looks clipped which is  even worse.